# How to call powershell script from c shsarp (c#) for setting ACL in folder

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, scripting

This is my c# code to call powershell script

```
IDictionary<string, object> param5= new Dictionary<String, object>();
                param5.Add("Username", "username");
                param5.Add("FolderFilePath", FolderName);
                param5.Add("Security", "FullControl");
                param5.Add("AccessControlType", "Allow");
                param5.Add("Value1", "$true");
                param5.Add("Value2", "$true");
                cnt = Common.PowerShellScriptInvokerWithParam("SetAcl", param5);
```

I have defined method PowerShellScriptInvokerWithParam as

```
public static List<PSObject> PowerShellScriptInvokerWithParam(string scriptName, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            var scriptFile = Application.StartupPath.Replace(@"bin\Debug", "") + @"\PowerShellScripts\" + scriptName + ".ps1";

            // Validate parameters
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(scriptFile)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("scriptFile"); }
            if (parameters == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("parameters"); }

            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
            {
                runspace.Open();
                RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
                scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                Command scriptCommand = new Command(scriptFile);
                Collection<CommandParameter> commandParameters = new Collection<CommandParameter>();
                foreach (string scriptParameter in parameters.Keys)
                {
                    CommandParameter commandParm = new CommandParameter(scriptParameter, parameters[scriptParameter]);
                    commandParameters.Add(commandParm);
                    scriptCommand.Parameters.Add(commandParm);
                }
                pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptCommand);
                pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
                List<PSObject> psObjects;

                psObjects = pipeline.Invoke().ToList();
                return psObjects;
            }
        }
```

But getting error as

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
```

Powershell script is

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Username,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FolderFilePath,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Security,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$AccessControlType,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][bool]$Value1,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][bool]$Value2)
$acl = Get-Acl $FolderFilePath
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($Value1, $Value2)

#For "Security="FullControl","Read","Modify","Read Execute","Read","Write""

$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Username,$Security, "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "InheritOnly", $AccessControlType)
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl $FolderFilePath $acl
```

Expecting to change ACL in specified folder according to user input in script. When i run powershell script as an administrator manually. It's applying ACL.

Comment: Did you run the C# application as an Administrator?

Comment: Is there more stack trace info on the error? Would be nice to see which method was producing it, etc...

Comment: @NIck While doing debugging I am getting above mentioned error at ``` cnt = Common.PowerShellScriptInvokerWithParam("SetAcl", param5); ```

Comment: @EylM Yes i am running visual studio in administrator mode